# Map Domain to Directory on IIS

Tags: iis-8.5

I have found a few topics on this but not sure if they specifically relate to my question. I am busy creating a multi-tenant application and would like the following setup:

- http://tenant.example.com/ <- tenants site
- http://tenant.example.com/api <- tenants api which is generic.

I have two servers:

- tenanthost which is tenant.example.com
- apihost

Now is is possible to map apihost to /api on tenanthost on IIS8.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question what you want is a proxy pass through for http://tenant.example.com/api  to the api server.

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) wasn't written by me but does explain it well for IIS 8.0 (I can't see it being much different in 8.5).

Also search on ServerFault for questions about IIS reverse proxy.  There are many, for example [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/228154/reverse-proxy-and-iis).

Comment: Thank you very much, the article pointed me in the right direction!